# Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* not working properly on Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, spring-mvc, cors

I have a web application running on Spring MVC using RESTful web services. I'm trying to send a JSON to those web services from an HTML/Javascript file. Here's the Javascript:

```
$.ajax
(
{
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/proj/service",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        callback(data);
    }
}
);
```

And the mapping in Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proj/service/", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView procRequest(@RequestBody String paramsJson, HttpServletResponse resp, WebRequest request_p){        

        resp.setStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
        resp.setHeader("Location", request_p.getContextPath() + "/proj/service");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
            //Code
}
```

For some reason when I delete the contentType key from the ajax request it goes through, but of course it is in an incorrect format since I expect the Javascript to send me a JSON string. But for some reason if I leave the contentType key I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/proj/service/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I don't know what could possibly be causing this error since the appropiate header is there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/listActions")
public @ResponseBody List<Action> list(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    List<Action> actions =  new ArrayList<Action>();
    actions.add(new Action(1, "Do something fantastic"));
    actions.add(new Action(2, "Save the world"));
    actions.add(new Action(3, "Buy beer"));
    actions.add(new Action(4, "Butcher a hog"));
    return actions;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Content-Type` header triggers a CORS preflight request. You need to modify your handler to respond to an `OPTIONS` request with the following headers:

```
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

This should send the appropriate response to the preflight request, after which the browser will issue the actual request. You can learn more about preflight requests here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: it doesn't look like it's an issue with the preflight request, as it would be explicit in the trace otherwise that the OPTIONS method failed.

Comment: @plus, which trace are you referring to? The error in the browser's console log looks the same regardless of whether the preflight fails or the actual request fails.

Comment: Cause when you have an issue with the preflight you get both errors: `OPTIONS http://foo/bar Origin http://foo is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` and then 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo/bar. Origin http://foo is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm not seeing that in my browser. If the preflight fails, the actual request should never go through, so there should be one request anyway.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Maybe they added that to give a more specific error then if a requested header or method was missing.

Comment: Ah you are right. I think this is new behavior in Chrome, since when I checked a few weeks back, it didn't behave like this. When the original poster wrote this question, it didn't behave like this. However, the issue is still the same: even though there are 2 errors in the Console, switching over to the Network tab shows that there is only one request (the preflight request only).